# How to run executable jar file created using maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, jar

We are working on Automation Testing which uses selenium and Junit . Our requirement is to make an executable jar file using Maven. Project Structure is look like this

```
  Project 
   |src\main\java
   |src\main\res
   |src\test\java
       |testmain
           |MainTest.java
   |src\test\res
   |target
   |pom.xml
```

We are using maven assembly plugin to create jar file

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>testMain.MainTest</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>`
```

we can able to create jar file(SampleMaven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar) using this command .

> clean package assembly:single

But when we try to run it using

> java -jar SampleMaven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

we are getting this error

> Could not find or load main class testMain.MainTest

Please help me to resolve this error

EDIT:

As i mentioned above ,i couldn't have MainTest.java in src/main folder since our project is only about automation testing which uses selenium primarily . selenium/junit is test framework which does not work under src/main . Please let me know if there is any other approach to resolve this conflict.

Comment: Please don't post an image, post the structure as text. Does the class `testMain.MainTest` exist? Can you unzip your JAR and see if it's there?

Comment: Do you have the `main` method in your `MainTest` class?

Comment: All files in the ``/src/test`` folder don't get packaged into the jar. Place your ``MainTest`` class in ``/src/main``. ``/src/test`` should contain your project's test files (unit tests etc) and are not part of the final artifact.

Answer (score 3):

Place all the files that are supposed to be part of the packaged jar into `/src/main`, not `/src/test`.

`/src/test` should contain your project's test files (unit tests etc) and are not part of the final artifact. That's why java cannot find the class in the jar.

Comment: we are using cucumber/junit to run our test . cucumber/junit doesn't work when we have under `/src/main` .